# Apple Script Increse variable

Tags: applescript

Hi there im trying to create and applescript to run within the theatre Cueing software 'Qlab'

```
tell application id "com.figure53.qlab.3" 
    set cueChannel to 16
    set cueControlChangeNumber to 16
    set cueControlValue to 0

    make type "MIDI"
    set newCue to last item of (selected as list)
    set channel of newCue to cueChannel
    set q name of newCue to DiGiCo
    set command of newCue to control_change
    set byte one of newCue to cueControlChangeNumber
    set byte two of newCue to cueControlValue
end tell
```

What I need to happen is for 'byte two' to start at 0 and increase by 1 to a max value of 127.

This script needs to run individually each time.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use a repeat block. Not certain how much code you wanted repeat for each iteration.

```
tell application id "com.figure53.qlab.3" 
    set cueChannel to 16
    set cueControlChangeNumber to 16

    repeat with cueControlValue from 0 to 127
        make type "MIDI"
        set newCue to last item of (selected as list)
        set channel of newCue to cueChannel
        set q name of newCue to DiGiCo
        set command of newCue to control_change
        set byte one of newCue to cueControlChangeNumber
        set byte two of newCue to cueControlValue
    end
end tell
```